# What do you call a building where you can view a historical attraction?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm designing a small building for my university where you can come and relax and take pictures and most importantly, view the neighboring building through a lens "(which is a historical site).

So, can you guys tell me what would be the right name to call it by?

Comment: 'Viewing area' is a hypernym.

Comment: I'd check what they were called on airports (when airports used to have them).  Often "viewing platform".

Comment: I tried to clarify the question title as best as possible.  Merry Xmas!

Comment: @Fattie why does it have to be a historical "attraction", it sounds like the planned building overviews Mount Rushmore or something similar. Wouldn't a *historical monument* or *edifice* be more appropriate?

Comment: hey @Mari-LouA !  Best that you improve the title (i.e., edit it).  I tried my best to improve it from the original dismal title.  Hopefully you can do better.  In contemporary, native, USA, English, "attraction" encompasses precisely *historical monument* or *edifice* and other, well, attractions.  Note that Mt. Rushmore (the example you use) is, precisely, exactly, and ubiquitously, described as an "attraction".  Merry Xmas!

Comment: @Fattie I know that Mt. Rushmore is a tourist attraction, but the point I was trying to make is that the view is not scenic, the OP is talking about  a viewpoint overseeing a historical building. Merry Xmas to you as well :)

Comment: Roohina Khanum, is this small building situated in the country or in the city? And is this university in the US or in Europe/rest of the world?

Answer (score 2):

Observatory might be one answer.

Comment: now if you support that answer with some definitions and [examples](https://www.warhistoryonline.com/guest-bloggers/german-periscope-montfaucon.html) of it being used that way...

Comment: For me, "observatory" carries strong connotations of an astronomer's observatory - i.e., somewhere to look at the sky, rather than something on the ground.

Comment: Hey @EthanKaminski - you know, "observatory" is sometimes used in a, rather archaic or formal sense, to mean just that - not an astronomical observatory, but, well, something like the OP describes. But yeah, to any normal, you know, like, USA teen, it would just mean "place with the telescope science space crap".  So it's probably not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**vantage point**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vantage-point) which means a place from which you can get a clear view of the surroundings.

> From our lofty vantage point, we could see the city spread out below us.

Comment: The only problem with that is, it describes the quality, but it's not the term used for the thing on a building.  Say the final term chosen is "Observatory".  Then, yes, the "observatory" is a vantage point by design, but you wouldn't call it "the vantage point".

Answer (score 2):

Where I live,there are numerous mountain parks and trails.

An elevated area in a clearing of the woods which enables an overhead view of the entirety (or, a specific part) of the landscape is commonly called a ***lookout*** or, a ***lookout point***.

A small building at such a site (often with coin-operated binocular viewing machines) is called a ***lookout tower***.(US)

Comment: Yep and they often have a fixed telescope or binoculars like OP describes.

Comment: "Lookout" applies much more to vantage points **for scenery**.  (Or, unusually, in a military sense.)  The OP's question, apparently, is more about a sort of "historical building viewing station", you wouldn't call it a lookout.

Comment: @Fattie - Missed the "building" part... Please see edit.

Comment: lookout tower is probably perfect @oldbag , good one.  Merry Xmas!

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear as to the sort of building being proposed.  Is it just a gazebo with a telescope in it or is it a proper building with other uses and that happens to be situated in a scenic spot?  If it's in the U.S., you will surely want to incorporate the name of the major money donor into the title of the structure regardless of the sort of structure it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with *belvedere*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belvedere_%28structure%29):

> A **belvedere** /ˈbɛlvɪdɪər/ or **belvidere** (from Italian for "fair view") is an architectural structure sited to take advantage of a fine or scenic view.
>   While a belvedere may be built in the upper part of a building the actual structure can be of any form, whether a turret, a cupola, or an open gallery.
>   Or it may be a separate pavilion in a garden, or the term may be used for a paved terrace with a good viewpoint, but no actual building.

Answer (score 0):

If "view the neighboring building through a lens" is the significant part of this question, then perhaps it is a camera oscura?

Answer (score 0):

Observatory can also be used in a non stargazing context.

> A position or building that gives an extensive view.